# Django many-to-many: Get a list of categories from a list of articles

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-2.1

For the sake of simplicity let's say I only have 3 models: Articles, Categories, Author.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
    ...

class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
    ...

class Articles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    ...
```

I filter a list of articles by author_id `list_article = Articles.objects.filter(author_id=author_id)`

My question is, how do I retrieve a list of 'Categories' from that 'list_article'?

Thank you.

Comment: @ljmocic it returns all the categories in the database. I just want categories that has articles in `list_articles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` with the list of articles:

```
Category.objects.filter(articles__in=list_article)
```

Or do the joins directly to the author:

```
Category.objects.filter(articles__author_id=author_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, it does help solving my problem. Once I have the list of categories in a sidebar, I want to quick filter the list of articles on the main container, every time I click on one category. Could you please give me a suggestion?